# List all extensions of an object

Tags: c#

With `object.GetType().GetMethods()` you can list all methods of an object.
How can you list all extensions of an object ?

For example : 
I have this extension

```
public static void DoSomething(this MyObject obj, String param) {}
```

Is there a way to retrieve `DoSomething` method of object `MyObject` using reflections or an other method ?